# i want a subversion server in my wamp server?

Tags: windows-7, svn

i want to setup a subversion server in my home. i installed a wamp server in My PC. but little bit confused to install subversion. i have windows 7, 32-bit as operating system and Intel Core-IV processor with 4 GB RAM. when i install [usvn](https://trac.usvn.info/wiki/Documentation/Install) i get error

> Invalid controller specified (public) Trace:
>   C:\wamp\www\usvn\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php:954 
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard::dispatch
>   C:\wamp\www\usvn\public\index.php:5
>   Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch

if any one have any idea, i am thankful to you.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Offtopic for SF, must be in SU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UberSVN is more thab just http-based Subversion server, maybe you want less?

- Configure [own Apache](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) with SVN-modules (modules for Apache you get with [WANdisco Windows Subversion](http://www.wandisco.com/get/?f=subversion-binaries/1.7/WANdiscoSubversion_1.7.8-1.exe) or [Subversion for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/))

or

- Install additional Apache+SVN in the form of [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)